# How to bind a ModelView item from a ObservableCollection in xml?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, caliburn.micro

I have a IntegerModelView and IntegerView and i want to reuse then in other view.
I am able to bind a ModelView but I want to bind a collection and i do not know how to select whole item from itermsource.

```
 public class MultiValuedViewModel: PropertyChangedBase
    {
        private ObservableCollection<IntegerViewModel> _aded;
        private IntegerViewModel _header;
....


    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not checked, but something like this should work

```html
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Aded}">
   <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
         <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <!-- some data template -->
      </DataTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: It works propertly. Ijust need to add datatemplate. Thanks